# Why sql is so popular but I want to use archives

Tags: mysql, winrar

Cant I use winrar archive to store information instead of database sql?

Comment: How do you want to access your archived information?

Comment: Those are two completely separate tools for two completely separate jobs. SQL is used to relate and query individual pieces of data. WinRar is used to compress one or more files in a single file bundle. They are two completely separate things.

Comment: @DanielBlais php has archive commands. So I can create archive with data (such as text with name and surname, or pictures videos ext) then with zipmodule of php you can use this command

Comment: Try to do a benchmark comparing both of them. Nothing stop you doing it. But, a SQL database is made on the purpose of using data, writing, sharing it, not a rar archive.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it here:

Sql is so popular since it is a way to ask for ordered information. For example if you have a company who sells cars you can enter all sales of cars into a sql database.
Then you can easily ask for how many sales have i had this month/week etc.

And you can order how many sales grouped by color of the car for example.

Sql is a way to ask for information in the database and you can ask conditions like how many cars was sold only on mondays, this way you can try to find which day is the day most people buy cars or get reports of who sold the most cars this month and deserves a bonus.

Winrar compresses files only to save space. If you have a report of all sales in files and then compress them you have one file that is compressed that you can't (easily) search in. This is useful if you want to send large files, then you can compress them into a single file to make it easier and also to make the file smaller than all the original files combined so it goes faster to send by email for example.

Two completely different things. But both are good so try to learn more about both of them.